# Xr2206 sine wave oscillator

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

If xr2206 is used to generate a sine wave does it have dc component? Based on my analysis it does not have.

Comment: so, if that is what your analysis says, why doubt? Also, note that the XR2206 is *really* a strange circuit, and I honestly doubt it's the easiest way to get a sine wave, and atop of that, its frequency accuracy depends on a capacitor – that's bad news.

Comment: I cant simulate xr2206 in any software that's why i doubt. Thank you for helping. Maybe i can  just use sgnal generator to produce 30kHz frequency and 9Vp-p for my inductive power transfer.

Comment: Note that in addition to other comments there are also some very badly done ***fake*** XR2206 devices that abound on ebay and elsewhere. Just a note.

Answer (score 0):

I can design 2 circuits, both using an XR2206:

In circuit A there is **no** DC offset present at the sine wave output.

In circuit B there **is** a DC offset present at the sine wave output.

Note that in circuit A I have to use a symmetrical power supply, of for example +/- 5V.

Circuit B only uses a single 10 V supply.

Look at the test diagram in the datasheet, my circuit B would look like this:

[image]

Here a single supply is used so the output voltage **cannot go below 0 V** which means the "middle" of the sinewave must centered around a certain DC voltage.

So yes, if you also do not use a negative supply rail then there will be a DC offset on the Sinewave.

Comment: If i adjust the symmetry adjust to minimum what will happen? What if it is in maximum? Thanks for your  explanation it is a big help for me :)

Comment: And where will i put negative supply rail? Sorry if i have many questions about xr2206, it is my first time using it.

Comment: My sentence *the output voltage cannot go below 0 V* will still hold **no matter how you adjust the symmetry setting**. The symmetry setting only controls how **distorted** your sinewave will be, you can choose between: some distortion and more distortion. The XR2206 simply **isn't very good**. I you want a good sinewave: use a DDS like AD9850.

Comment: *And where will i put negative supply rail?* If you have to ask that then I suggest you look at other circuits using a negative supply and learn how it is done. You could also just use a **capacitor** in series with the output signal to eliminate the DC. Same way as is done in almost all audio circuits.

Comment: Ok ill try to look for AD9840 and find if it is better to use than xr2206. Thanks a lot your suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: It's the AD98**50** and it will also have a DC voltage at the output. To control the AD9850 you will need a microcontroller, for example an Arduino.

Comment: Oh i see. Ad9850 is controlled by microcontroller i think it is not suitable for my design but anyways thanks for your suggestion :)